# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/prayqxia/public_html/friendsofjesusnetwork.com/wp-content/themes/iamsocial/functions.php on line 36

Tags: wordpress

I tried to insert this code to my wordpress site, in my theme fuction.php file. that was when I start to experience this problem.

```
/**
 * Checks if a particular user has a role.
 * Returns true if a match was found.
 *
 * @param string $role Role name.
 * @param int $user_id (Optional) The ID of a user. Defaults to the current user.
 * @return bool
 */
function appthemes_check_user_role( $role, $user_id = null ) {

    if ( is_numeric( $user_id ) )
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    else
        $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( empty( $user ) )
    return false;

    return in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles );
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 36?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function appthemes_check_user_role( $role, $user_id = null ) {

    if ( is_numeric( $user_id ) ) {
      $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    } else {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
    }

    if ( empty( $user ) ) { return false; }

    return in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me try it in the next four minutes

Comment: Could you elaborate about what's different?  The only thing I see is that you've added `{}`.

Comment: I tried to edit my site, but I could not get to the dashboard any more

Comment: This error,   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/prayqxia/public_html/friendsofjesusnetwork.com/wp-content/themes/iamsocial/functions.php on line 36

Comment: Paste the entirety of the functions.php

Comment: I could not access my dashboard

Comment: log in to your server via FTP or cPanel and post here the contents of functions.php or just the first 40 rows